# Change Image in Google Map Ground Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I've added an image over the top of a Google Map and while I can remove (and add) this overlay what I'd really like to do is switch the image for another one.

```
var imageBounds = {
    north: 51.498304,
    south: 51.490996,
    east: -0.272327,
    west: -0.2787
};

accessabilityOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    templateUrl + '/img/access-bicycle.png',
    imageBounds);

accessabilityOverlay.setMap(map);
```

Googling the issue keeps taking me back to how it might be done with the Android API using 'BitmapDescriptorFactory' which I don't think is what I'm after.

How can I change the image within the ground overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GroundOverlay is an MVCObject which implements a setter-method `set`, the property you must set is `url`.

After changing the url you must call `setMap` again:

```
accessabilityOverlay.set('url','path/to/other/image.png');
accessabilityOverlay.setMap(map);
```